# Create a newEventHandler for a button. But Data fields are empty for some reason

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I create a new event Handler to handle two different events. One is for saving a new document. The other is for saving an edit.

I added this in my Page_load:

```
if (Request.QueryString["ExhibitID"] != null)//new
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlCaseFiles.DataSourceID = "dsCaseFiles";
        ddlCaseFiles.DataTextField = "Display";
        ddlCaseFiles.DataValueField = "FileID";
        rbByFileID.Checked = true;
        rbMyFiles.Checked = false;
        ddlCaseFiles.DataBind();
        editExhibit(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ExhibitID"]));//new
        exhibitHeader.InnerText = "Edit Exhibit";
    }
    hidSavedExhibitID.Value = Request.QueryString["ExhibitID"];
    saveExhibitBtn.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnUpdateExhibit_Click);
}
else
{
    saveExhibitBtn.Click += new EventHandler(this.saveExhibitBtn_Click);
}
```

my save method for some reason keeps looping then crashing because the second time it goes through, there is no data since I reset it after the first save. I have no idea why it is running my save method twice.

this is my save method :

```
 protected void saveExhibitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hidSavedExhibitID.Value = null;
    int newExhibitID = saveExhibit();

    int propertyID = autoCreateProperty(newExhibitID);
    linkExhibitAndProperty(newExhibitID, propertyID);

    SaveInfoIntoSessionVariables();
    ClearFormFields();
}
```

the "saveExhibit()" method is where I actually access the DB and store everything. It works fine.

Comment: Whoa, what a nasty piece of code (with multiple violations of a clean code and various principles)! Can't you show only the code relevant to the question? Or do you expect us to study it? This is an epic example of not understanding OOP. No wonder you can't debug it yourself...

Comment: Well I put it there because before people would give me heat because I post too little. And most of the code isn't mine. Someone else made it. I was just trying to figure out why all my input fields' values are "" or -1.

Comment: can you show the aspx code for those controls?

Comment: added it in the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you re bind your datas in your Page_Load.

You must persist your datas with ViewState, `EnableViewState="true"`

You bind your datas just one time, in the `! IsPostBack`. in order to not erase the selected values

```
If(! IsPostBack)
{

   //Bind your datas with `DataBind()`
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It makes so much sense now.

Comment: I'am happy that you solved your problem Thank you user1084319

Comment: Everything was working, but I've run into a little problem. I will put the question in the main post